# How to get value from my laravel controller and set it in the javascript file in public folder?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel. I have a function like this below in the controller. I want to get `$update_tugas_id` value and set it into the javascript in public folder. Do you know how?

```
public function getTugasDetailUpdate(Request $request)
{   
    $update_tugas_id = $request->get("V_ID_PK");
    $getDataListPengikut = DB::select("EXEC dbo.GET_KEMENPAR_LIST_PENGIKUT '".$update_tugas_id."'");
    $getPengikut2 = DB::select("EXEC dbo.LOV_M_PENGIKUT");
    $msg["opt"] ="";
    $no=1;
    foreach($getDataListPengikut as $dtListPengikut):
        $msg["opt"] .= '<tr>
            <td><select class="form-control" id="name_'.$dtListPengikut->KODE.'" name="nameupdate[]" data-live-search="true" style="width:100%">
                <option value=""> --Silahkan Pilih-- </option>'; 
                    foreach ($getPengikut2 as $getPeng){
                      $msg["opt"] .=   '<option value="'.$getPeng->KODE.'"@if( '.$dtListPengikut->DESKRIPSI.'=='.$getPeng->KODE.') selected @endif>'. $getPeng->DESKRIPSI .'</option>'; 
                    } 
                $msg["opt"] .='</select>
            </td> 
            if ($no == 1){   
            $msg["opt"] .=   '<td><button type="button" name="add" id="addupdate'.$no.'" onclick="addMe(this);return false" class="btn btn-success"><b>+</b></button>
                </td>';
            }
            else{
                $msg["opt"] .=   '<td><button type="button" name="remove" id="removeupdate'.$no.'" onclick="removeMe(this);return false" class="btn btn-danger"><b>x</b></button>
                </td>';
            }
            $msg["opt"] .=  '</tr>';
            $no++;
            endforeach;
       echo json_encode($msg);
}
```

And this below is my javascript. I want to set the value into the `var optionS = $('#name_3').html();` line, 3 in that I want to change with the value that I get from my controller.

```
var i=1;
function addMe(e){
var optionS = $('#name_3').html();
i++;
$('#dynamic_field_update').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td><select class="form-control" id="name_3" name="nameupdate[]" data-live-search="true" style="width:100%">'+optionS+' </select></td><td><input type="text" name="ketupdate[]" placeholder="Keterangan" style="text-transform:uppercase" class="form-control ket_list" required /></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="newremoveupdate'+i+'" onclick="removeMe(this);return false" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove"><b>x</b></button></td></tr>'); 
    }
```

Comment: You can create an ajax call ?

Comment: I called `getTugasDetailUpdate` function with ajax

Answer (score 1):

It's generally a bad approach to form the `HTML` inside of your controller and then send it back in a request to the frontend, but to store it inside javascript variable you can do so like this:

```
var optionS = '{!! $html !!}'; //{!! and !!} displays unescaped data
```

If you wish to store a `non-HTML` response into your variable you can put it like this:

```
var optionS = '{{ $variable }}'; //{{ and }} displays escaped data
```

But the best approach to display escaped data **in case where that variable is not long** is to make a tag inside of `HTML` and add an attribute like `data-username` for example and put the username there, then you can fetch it with javascript.

```
<div data-username="{{ $username }}"></div>
```

**It's generally a bad idea to transfer any IMPORTANT variables or HTML from your controller into the View and use them like above, you should avoid it when possible.**